# VB.NET application randomly spawns another instance of itself during use

Tags: vb.net, winforms, random, process, spawn

I have a Windows forms application which I have a bit of a sporadic issue with. The application would randomly start/spawn another instance of itself without any warning or reason. I only have one use of Process.Start in the whole application (15 forms/files and about 5000 lines of code) and that calls a net use command to map a network drive.

I've not been able to reproduce this in my testing and therefore I made the project a Windows Assembly Framework single instance application (pros/cons of this I know). This has obviously stopped any other instances of the application from running, but now at random intervals their program will minimise and snap to another application they have running. I don't know for certain whether this is related but they certainly sound a bit close for comfort!

Any ideas/pointers/thoughts appreciated.

Thanks,

Jamie

Comment: What´s the Windows event log saying?

Comment: Nothing at all which I can see is related, typical Windows messages. One WMI issue which is permissions related at boot, apart from that nothing untoward on any of the machines I've checked out

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if the application, at some point, calls [Application.Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx).

Comment: Application.Restart isn't being used at all in their entire project